# Help with exploring the possibiltiy of "long distance" wireless charging

Tags: wireless, charging, wireless-charging

I have a question regarding the possibility of wireless charging (via coils and pads.)

Essentially, I am trying to develop a product that will require charging from a car's battery and will be placed inside the car.

I want some advice on the possibility of connecting essentially a large wireless charger pad (as this will be in the car and not be portable, size is not particularly a concern, although this length should not surpass 45cm.) The device receiving the power will also be large (although parameters are not entirely set, likely 27 inches from corner to corner.) I need the transmission range to reach 20-30cm for this idea to be plausible.

From my basic understanding of wireless charging, the reason such distance is not possible in say phones is due to restrictions in coil sizes. Does this mean that this transmission length would be possible under these parameters?

Comment: Can you say what power level you are interested in, as this has a major impact on overall system viability.

Comment: hard to say with 100% certainty but i would not expect it to surpass 100w, 150w at an absolute maximum, but most likely in the 75W range

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What will be under the pad? Steel car body?

Comment: the pad would be rested on either the car seat or felt body lining inside, so not on the cars metal body